# When i using solcx to compile my contract i got some error

Tags: solidity, python, py-solc-x

I need to using solc to compile my contract,but i got some error when i compile the contract, here is my counter contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;
import "./NFTMarket.sol";  //this is the erc721 contract i wrote

contract NFTCounter {
    address private _contractOwner;   
    mapping(uint256 => address) public IndContract;       
    NFTMarket public _NFTMarket;                   
    uint256 public AddCounter;                     


    constructor(){
        _contractOwner = msg.sender;
        AddCounter = 0;
    }
    modifier onlyContractAdmin() {
        require(msg.sender == _contractOwner, "Only the contract owner can do this 
action.");
        _;
    }
    function addIndContract(uint256 Ind_Contract ,address NFT_addr) public {
        IndContract[Ind_Contract] = NFT_addr;
        AddCounter++;
    }
    function mintTo(uint256 Ind_Contract , address to , uint256 Ind_mint) public 
onlyContractAdmin returns(bool){
        NFTMarket contract_ = NFTMarket(IndContract[Ind_Contract]);
        contract_.mint(Ind_mint,to);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And my python code is here.

```
from ast import main
from solcx import compile_source,install_solc,compile_standard
import json


def main():
    install_solc("0.8.11")

    file_path = './chainlink/contracts/NFTCounter.sol'

    with open(file_path, "r",encoding='utf8') as file:
        counter = file.read()

    compiled_sol = compile_standard(
        {
            "language": "Solidity",
            "sources": {"NFTCounter.sol": {"content": counter}},
            "settings": {
                "outputSelection": {
                    "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
                }
            },
        },
        solc_version="0.8.11",
    )
    with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

And i got the error is here

> exception occurs: SolcError
> ParserError: Source "NFTMarket.sol" not found: File not found.
> --> NFTCounter.sol:5:1:
> |
> 5 | import "./NFTMarket.sol";
> | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

> command: `C:\Users\tsai\.solcx\solc-v0.8.11\solc.exe --standard-json`
> return code: `0`
> stdout:
> {"errors":[{"component":"general","errorCode":"6275","formattedMessage":"ParserError: Source "NFTMarket.sol" not found: File not found.\n --> NFTCounter.sol:5:1:\n  |\n5 | import "./NFTMarket.sol";\n  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n\n","message":"Source "NFTMarket.sol" not found: File not found.","severity":"error","sourceLocation":{"end":164,"file":"NFTCounter.sol","start":139},"type":"ParserError"}],"sources":{}}

> stderr:
> File "D:\Quteng\flask\chainlink\scripts\practice.py", line 14, in main
> compiled_sol = compile_standard(
> File "D:\Quteng\flask\chainlink\scripts\practice.py", line 32, in 
> main()

Comment: Is `NFTMarket` in the same directory of `NFTCounter` ?

Comment: Yes~They are all in the `./chainlink/contracts/`
Or i should flatten the dependent contract ?